# How to use CTTypesetterSuggestClusterBreak in Core Text

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-text

I am having trouble in using CTTypesetterSuggestClusterBreak function of CTTypeSetterRef class. I want to use this method to get closest word boundry near an index. I am having difficult in the implementationof this method, i.e how and where this method must be used.
I have been banging my head over this but with no success yet. If anyone can help me in using this method I would be very greatful.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure CoreText is appropriate for this task; it sounds like you should investigate `CFStringTokenizer` instead.